# how to make animation like notification drawer icon movement and size change during drag down in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I know how to animate translate, zoom and also value animator. But I'm wondering how to achieve the animation like notification drawer, the icon and button move and scale change as we drag down the notification drawer.

Please point out the tips and step to do the animation like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be better if you can give more details about what you want to achieve.

But I think you can try to using Motion Layout, it's now is available since Constraint Layout 2.0.

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/defining-motion-paths-in-motionlayout-6095b874d37)

And also refer to vector icon animation [here](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-delightful-details)

Comment: What I mention is in Android, when we drag down notification bar, there are buttons for wifi, screen rotation, Bluetooth, airplane mode button. They are changing position, size, and transparency according to your drag position. I want to animate layout like that.

Comment: Thanks, Khoa Tran, you save me. What I'm looking is Motion Layout.